# Angular 1.6: Abrir um uibmodal dentro de outro uibmodal usando "resolve"?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Estou com um problema para abrir um uibmodal dentro de outro uibmodal passando o mesmo através do resolve.
Tenho dois modals declarados dentro de um mesmo controller, Modal1 e Modal2.
Modal 1 passa o modal2 no resolve, tudo funciona bacana, menos a questão do "result.then", o modal 2 retorna um valor x para um $scopo, porém o mesmo retorna o valor para o controller principal e eu gostaria que fosse retornado para o Modal1

Veja o exemplo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ltzJzn27413sQ17YThoX?p=preview

Alguém sabe como resolver esta questão? Já tentei usar angular.copy mas não funciona :(

Muito Obrigado

Comment: Mostre o que você tentou ate agora.

Comment: Olá Lucas, eu coloquei o exemplo do código no plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ltzJzn27413sQ17YThoX?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção é fazer com que a função de abrir modals receba um callback:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {

  //abre um Modal
  function openModal( templateUrl, controller, resolve, callback ){
    return $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl,
      controller,
      resolve
    }).result.then( callback || angular.noop );
  }

  //abre modal 1
  const openModal1 = (resolve, callback) => 
    openModal( 'modaltemplate1.html', 'ModalController1', resolve, callback);

  //abre modal 2
  const openModal2 = (resolve, callback) =>
    openModal( 'modaltemplate2.html', 'ModalController2', resolve, callback);


  $scope.produtos = 0;

  $scope.openModal1 = function () {
    openModal1({
      openModal2: function() {
        //envia a função de abrir o modal 2
        return openModal2;
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.openModal2 = () => openModal2({},  result => $scope.produtos = result);

});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalController1', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, openModal2) {

  $scope.produtos = 1;

  $scope.ok = () => $uibModalInstance.close($scope.produtos);

  $scope.openModal2 = () => openModal2({}, result => $scope.produtos = result );

});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalController2', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal) {

  $scope.produtos = 2;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.produtos);
  };

});
```

Comment: Agora como eu faço para chamar o modal2 dentro do meu controller principal?
http://plnkr.co/edit/ltzJzn27413sQ17YThoX?p=preview

Comment: Atualizei para ficar mais fácil.

Comment: Muito obrigado! ;)